# ActiveRecord find() with negated condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I can't seem to find a solution to what seems to me like a simple problem.

```
Sitemap.find(:all, :conditions => { :controller => 'sample', :action => '!index' })
```

Now obviously the ! in 'index' doesn't belong there, but I put it there to illustrate that I want any result EXCEPT 'index'.  I've tried something like the line below but I've gotten server errors whenever I try it.

```
Sitemap.find(:all, :conditions => { :controller => 'sample', "action <> 'index'" })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the array syntax for this:

```
Sitemap.all(:conditions => ["controller = ? AND action <> ?", 'sample', 'index']
```

Hash syntax is only useful if you're checking for equality.